# How to install the uploaded Voice command definition(VCD) file to another windows phone application?

Tags: voice-recognition, cortana

I want to upload the VCD file through an through application A and need to install that uploaded files to other Cortana application B. How can I achieve that? Any answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naveen,
I think instead of having a separate app, You can have a setting to upload VCD through application A itself. To say correctly, you should upload the VCD file through the app A and install it straight away from there. That would be more intuitive.

Comment: Actually My requirement was to create a separate app. But I would consider your idea as it is more intuitive as you said. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Still I am keen to know the possibility of installing VCD commands to a Cortana app from another app.